# Ajax Call Windows8 Permission

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, permissions

I am experiencing a weird problem, and believe it is privileges, but not sure where to find the problem? I created a simple html test page to do a ajax call to my webserver when I click a button.

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;
    var pageUrl = 'http://webservice.svn/WebService1.asmx';

   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: pageUrl + "/Helloworld",
        data: '{}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert(response.status + " " + response.statusText);
        }
    });
```

Running the html page with URI adress http://mobile.svn/test.html - I am getting Error 0, but running as URI - c:\Mobile\test.html it is returning Hello World. So I can see it is the ajax that is failing when running through IIS
I am running windows 8.1
Thanks

**Update**
[image]

Comment: Error 0 usually indicates a CORS error, the request could not be made for some reason. What error message do you get in your browser's console? That should give you something more specific.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, so it seems it is some kind of CORS error, but if I set support.cors to false I get a no transport error

Answer (score 0):

Its because of Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) for post request. post cross domain requests are blocked by the browser security.

Here you can find some help

http://techblog.constantcontact.com/software-development/using-cors-for-cross-domain-ajax-requests/

Comment: While this is true, your answer does not offer any answers to how to fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

Thanks abmichelle! You directed me in the right direction.
My webservice didn't have customHeaders in the webconfig... :-)

```
<customHeaders>
   <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
   <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE"/>
   <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Accept"/>
</customHeaders>
```